Average value of a function $f(\alpha)= \frac {\cos\beta}{1-\sin^2\alpha \cdot \sin^2\beta}$
Good evening, I have the following function:
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(\alpha\right) =
\frac {\cos\left(\beta\right)}{1 - \sin^{2}\left(\alpha\right)\sin^{2}\left(\beta\right)}
\quad\mbox{where}\ \beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I would like to demonstrate that, for each value of $\beta$, the average value of the function in the interval $\left[0,2\pi\right]$ is $1$.
$$
\mbox{So it should just be:}\quad
m_{\left[0,2\pi\right]}=1=
{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\beta\right)}{1 - \sin^{2}\left(\alpha\right)\sin^{2}\left(\beta\right)} \,{\rm d}\alpha
$$
Unfortunately I don't know how to solve the denominator integral, do you have any suggestions on this ?.
Thank you.

For $\beta=\frac{3\pi}4$ it is -1.  Isn't it?

@BobDobbs Yes. The correct result for the average is $\operatorname{sgn}(\cos(\beta))$. The answers below implicitly assume $\cos(\beta) > 0$ when taking the square root/plugging in the limits of integration.

I tried to make a connection of this integral with $\zeta(2)$ by double integral. İ couldn,'t succeed. Is there a connection? Quanto knows maybe.

In case that $\sin(\beta)=\pm 1$ the integral is equal to $0$, this case is omitted.
First, notice that the integrand is symmetric with respect to $\pi$, so that $$\int_0^ {2\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha) \cdot \sin^2(\beta)}\,d\alpha=2\int_0^ {\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha) \cdot \sin^2(\beta)}\,d\alpha$$
Now,  $$\dfrac{1}{1-\sin^2(\beta)\sin^2(\alpha)}=\dfrac{1/2}{1-\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}+\dfrac{1/2}{1+\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}$$
and so $$\dfrac{\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\beta)\sin^2(\alpha)}=\dfrac{\cos(\beta)/2}{1-\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}+\dfrac{\cos(\beta)/2}{1+\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}$$
We will then have $$\int_0^ {2\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha) \cdot \sin^2(\beta)}\,d\alpha=\int_0^ {\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin(\alpha) \cdot \sin(\beta)}\,d\alpha+\int_0^ {\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1+\sin(\alpha) \cdot \sin(\beta)}\,d\alpha$$
Using the classic substituion $u=\tan(\alpha/2)$ we find that an antiderivative for the first integrand is $$2\arctan\left(\dfrac{\tan(\alpha/2)-\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)}\right)$$
Evaluating at $0$ and $\pi$ (taking the limit in the latter) we get $$\int_0^ {\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin(\alpha) \cdot \sin(\beta)}\,d\alpha=\pi+2\arctan(\tan(\beta))$$
Analogously, an antiderivative for the second integrand is $$2\arctan\left(\dfrac{\tan(\alpha/2)+\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)}\right)$$
And so $$\int_0^ {\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1+\sin(\alpha) \cdot \sin(\beta)}\,d\alpha=\pi-2\arctan(\tan(\beta))$$
Adding these results, we conclude $$\boxed{\int_0^ {2\pi} \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha) \cdot \sin^2(\beta)}\,d\alpha=(\pi+2\arctan(\tan(\beta)))+(\pi-2\arctan(\tan(\beta)))=2\pi}$$

Many thanks for the quick and clear demonstration!

How about regarding, with $c < 1$:
$\quad I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-c\sin^2\alpha} \mathrm d \alpha$
$$I=4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{c-\frac{1}{\sin^2\alpha}}\frac{\mathrm d \alpha}{\sin^2\alpha }
=-4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{c-\frac{\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}}{\mathrm d \cot\alpha}
\\ = 
- 4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{c-1 -  \cot^2\alpha}{\mathrm d \cot\alpha}
=  4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{c-1-x^2}\mathrm dx
\\= 4 \; \frac{\arctan(x/\sqrt{1 - c})|_0^{\infty}}{\sqrt{1-c}} = 2 \pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c}}$$
Now with $c = \sin^2 \beta$ we have $I = 2 \pi \frac{1}{\cos \beta}$
and that gives your result.

Hint
$$f(\alpha)= \frac {\cos(\beta)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha)\, \sin^2(\beta)}$$
Make it nicer usng the double angle formula
$$f(\alpha)=\frac 12 \,\frac {\sec ^2(\alpha )\, } {1+\tan ^2(\alpha ) \cos ^2(\beta ) }\,\,(1+\cos (2 \beta ))\,  \sec (\beta )$$
I am sure that you see now the change of variable to be used.
